# GPARTED : Merge partition with unallocated partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a problem with my partitions, The schema of my disk is:

- dev/sda3 - ntfs - 93.40GiB
- dev/sda4 - extended - 356.15GiB
- unallocated - unallocted - 356.15GiB

I want to merge the partition of 93 GB with the unallocated, but I do not know how to accomplish this.

Can anybody can help me please ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You can only merge partitions that are next to eachother. So you need to merge sda4 with unallocated; then split sda4 into unallocated and sda4 (ie. unallocated moves in between sda3 and sda4). And then merge sda3 with the unallocated that is now between sda3 and sda4

Comment: Can you please share result of `sudo fdisk /dev/sda -l` for confirmation?

Answer (score 3):

Your `sda4` "extended" is sort of [secondary partition table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_boot_record). If you are not planning to use more than 4 partitions in the future - and it looks like you don't, as you want to assign all the available space - just delete it, and then extend your `sda3`.

In other words: `sda4` is not an actual partition with files, and you don't have to worry about merging any data, just extend `sda3`.

Comment: With the info provided, I think like you, sda4 is an empty extended partition, so delete it and extend sda3

Comment: And of course, before any partition table manipulation, backup first!

Answer (score 0):

Extended partitions can certainly have data, traditionally it just meant that you had more than 4 primary partitions at one time.

SOP is to find another disk, and copy the partitions, leaving space for your intended growth between them rather than after them.

Then resize the filesystem to fill the larger partition. You can then copy the whole disk back.